# Alternate app icons as on-demand resources

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, on-demand-resources

Our largest contributor to binary size is alternate app icons. To reduce binary size and to prevent the unused alternate app icons from impacting everyone who uses our app, we'd like to move alternate app icons into [Apple's on-demand resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html).

Is this possible?

Currently our app icon files lack the Attributes Inspector section for on-demand resource tags, suggesting that this is not possible. (See below images.)

---

Image with On Demand Resource Tag section

[image: With "On Demand Resource Tag"]

---

Image without On Demand Resource Tag section

[image: Without "On Demand Resource Tag"]

Comment: Not answering your question, but have you considered using a custom icon font? Icons from custom fonts are scalable, easy to use or customize, faster to load, and really light. The only constraint is that you must use texts instead of images, or create your images *just in time*.